# Performance issue with converting matplot figure to bytestream

Tags: performance, python-2.7, matplotlib, figure

Solved the problem per se with the following code:

```
    sio = cStringIO.StringIO()
    fig.savefig(sio, format='png')
    image_chunks = sio.getvalue()
```

The remaining problem is the speed of these operations.

A figure with 900 pixel width and 900 pixel height will be processes within about 190ms. A figure with 11000 * 900 needs nearly 1600ms. In my case large horizontally scrollable figures come up often. The transformation to a bytestring is a real bottleneck in my application.

Any ideas to speed the procedure up?

Comment: I guess the bottleneck is not the streaming but matplotlib rendering the figure. What is the content of the figures? If you only show images you might get better results if you save the images directly to a bytestring, circumventing matplotlib.

Comment: I´m actually generating charts with matplotlib, so no way around it.